# Nginx MP4-pseudo-streaming + proxy_cache

Tags: nginx, streaming, mp4, reverse-proxy

I have a hard time getting Nginx's MP4-module's pseudo streaming to work with the proxy-cache-module.

I have following in my site configuration:

```
location ~* ^/stream/(\w+)/(\w+).mp4 {

    mp4;
    mp4_buffer_size     1m;
    mp4_max_buffer_size 15m;

    add_header X-Location "$1.$2";

    proxy_cache             cache-key-1;
    proxy_cache_valid       200     1d;
    proxy_cache_key         $2;
    proxy_pass              http://$1.servers.com/storage/$2.mp4;
    break;
}
```

Does pseudo streaming and proxying work together at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does pseudo streaming and proxying work together at all?

The mp4 module works for local files only. You should do streaming on your backend servers.